# How to update ruby gem re-readline 5.0 to rb-readline 5.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am working on ruby on rails and I want to update gem rb-readline 5.0 to rb-readline 5.1 . I am new in this field and want to know how to update this single gem step by step .Kindly help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to increase chances of your question being answered, I recommend asking a more specific question, including your code and listing things that you have tried. See [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

*Sidenote*: `rb-readline` gem has neither `5.0` nor `5.1` version. It’s current version [is `0.5.3`](https://github.com/ConnorAtherton/rb-readline/tree/v0.5.3). I assume you want to upgrade to `0.5.1`.

---

#### Current gemset update (no `Gemfile`)

If you wanted to upgrade to the current version, simple

```
gem update rb-readline
# update globally: 
# sudo gem -g update rb-readline
```

would do. In case to up-/down-grade to a specific version, the process is a bit tricky:

```
gem install rb-readline -v 0.5.1
# at this moment you have two different versions of gem installed
gem uninstall rb-readline -v 0.5.0
```

or, alternatively, one might simply call

```
gem uninstall rb-readline
```

to invoke the interactive prompt, asking what version is to be removed.

---

#### Rails / `Gemfile`

In Rails, there is usually a `Gemfile` in the root directory of the project. Open it with your preferred editor, find a line containing `rb-readline` and change it to (or add a new line, if it is an implicit dependency):

```
gem 'rb-readline', '~> 0.5', '= 0.5.1'
```